# Solving for the matrix $W$ in an equation involving $W \cdot W^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-programming

Having large matrices, $W$ (the unknown) and $M$ (known), is it possible to solve for $W$ in this equation
$$W \cdot W^{T} = M,$$
where $M$ can have negative entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for the [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). The referenced article also contains an example for  $M$ having negative entries. Note the constraints on $M$ for this decomposition to exist.

Comment: Even in Cholesky decomposition, the equation is solved by assuming $W$ to be made up of rows containing $a_{11},a_{12}\ldots a_{1n}$ and then equating the corresponding entries  of $WW^T$with $M$. Isn't this the brute force algorithm?